# Embeeded *ngFor in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-directives

Hi i have a problem with embeeded *ngFor loop. I try to make make something like that.

```
<div *ngFor = let console of consoles>
...
...
<li *ngFor = let pad of console.pad>
{{pad}
</li>
...
...
</div>
```

I tryed to put [innerHtml] data binding and it works but i have to make that second ngFor working because it will work great with my css styling.

Thank you in advance.

PS. I'm using Angular4

Comment: What's the problem? How is `[innerHTML]` related to the question?

Comment: This is totally possible, here's a quick example: https://plnkr.co/edit/BjRs1ZhwTiC9drKo7xLn?p=preview

Comment: The second *ngFor doesn't work, it doesn't display anything, i just informed [innerHtml] worked.

Comment: The solution @Brocco gave you is working - if that approach isn't working for you, then it's probably `console.pad` that's either empty or simply not an array

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean use innerHTML in the {{pad}} location?
you may try this way if so:

```
<div *ngFor = let console of consoles>
    ...
    ...
    <li *ngFor = let pad of console.pad>
        <span [innerHTML] = {{pad}}></span>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```